# Move up directory until folder found python

Tags: python

I have a package of the following format:

```
Electricity
|___ __main__.py
|
|__ Electricity
|    |___ general_functions
|    |___ regression_calcs
|    |    |___ create_calcs.py
|    |
|    |____ run_calcs.py
|
|
|
|__ Data_Input
     |___ regression_vals
          |__ regression_vals.csv
```

`run_calcs.py` runs the code in `regression_calcs`, which requires data from `Data_Input/Regression_vals`.

What is the most pythonic way to find the number of `../` (number of times to go up a folder), until `Data_Input` is found?

This is because right now I'm running the scripts in `Electricity/Electricity/run_calcs.py` (for testing). Eventually I will be running in `Electricity/__main__.py`.

it will be for `df = pd.read_csv(f'{filepath}Data_Input/regression_vals/regression_vals.csv')`
where `filepath = '../'*n`

Comment: Why do you need to loop through? Can you not just pass a the parent directory of `run_calcs.py` to the call in `regression_calcs`? Do these levels change? Can you show the call in `run_calcs.py`?

Comment: that's the thing, I want to not hardcode the filepath. However, say I run the file in `Electricity/Electricity/regression_calcs`, I will need to go up twice (so `../../Data_Input)`. Similarly, if I run in `Electricity/__main__.py`, I would not need to go up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your files within `regression_calcs`:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import join, isdir, dirname, basename

filepath = None
# get parent of the .py running
par_dir = dirname(__file__)
while True:
    # get basenames of all the directories in that parent
    dirs = [basename(join(par_dir, d)) for d in listdir(par_dir) if isdir(join(par_dir, d))]
    # the parent contains desired directory
    if 'Data_Input' in dirs:
        filepath = par_dir
        break
    # back it out another parent otherwise
    par_dir = dirname(par_dir)
```

Of course this only works if you have a single `'/Data_Input/'` directory!

Comment: Mhmm, it is only the one. I was wondering if there was going to be a neater way of doing it, but I guess I'll be looping through. Thanks

Comment: Well if this is a package where you will have other programs call `import Electricity`, then in `main.py` you can do this once (downwards) then in other files simply `from Electricity import DATA_INPUT` where `DATA_INPUT` is a constant path set in `main.py`.

Comment: yep, but for the time being, whilst I am piecing all the bits that make up the program together, I won't be using main.py. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Be careful if you are using `main.py` as a _script_, the path wont be added to `sys.path` so that `from Electricity...` call I am talking about wont work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Unipath](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unipath).

```
path = Path("/Electricity/Data_Input/regression_vals/regression_vals.csv")
path = path.parent
path = path.parent
```

And now `path` refers to **/Electricity/Data_Input** directory.

Comment: OP said they dont want to hardcode anything like that

Comment: Not sure what that piece of code does @avix. That gives me the parent of my file's location, not how to get to it. I need to go from my current file location TO the location in path.

Comment: I gave you the fastest way to move upwards directory. Now you can use loop and call `.parent` until you get to desired directory.

Answer (score 1):

What I eventually used (a mix between avix & pstatic's answer):

```
import os, unipath
def rel_location():
    """Goes up until it finds the folder 'Input_Data', then it stops
    returns '' or '../' or '../../', or ... depending on how many times it had to go up"""
    path = unipath.Path(__file__)
    num_tries = 5
    for num_up_folder in range(num_tries):
        path = path.parent
        if 'Input_Data' in os.listdir(path):
            break

    if num_tries == num_up_folder:
        raise FileNotFoundError("The directory 'Input_Data' could not be found in the 5"
                                " directories above this file's location. ")
    location = '../'* num_up_folder
    return location
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate implementation using `pathlib` and directly returning a Path object for the desired directory.

```
from pathlib import Path

def get_path_to_rel_location(directory_to_find):
    """Goes up in directory heirarchy until it finds directory that contains 
    `directory_to_find` and returns Path object of `directory_to_find`"""
    path = Path.cwd()
    num_tries = 5
    for num_up_folder in range(num_tries):
        path = path.parent
        if path / directory_to_find in path.iterdir():
            break

    if num_tries == num_up_folder:
        raise FileNotFoundError(f"The directory {directory_to_find} could not be found in the {num_tries}"
                                f" directories above this file's location.")
    return path / directory_to_find

# Example usage
path = get_path_to_rel_location("Input_Data")
```

Answer (score 0):

[os.scandir](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.scandir) is useful for stuff like this.

```
def find_my_cousin(me, cousin_name):
    """Find a file or directory named `cousin_name`. Start searching at `me`,
    and traverse directly up the file tree until found."""
    if not os.path.isdir(me):
        parent_folder = os.path.dirname(me)
    else:
        parent_folder = me
    folder = None

    removed = -1
    while folder != parent_folder:  # Stop if we hit the file system root
        folder = parent_folder
        removed += 1
        with os.scandir(folder) as ls:
            for f in ls:
                if f.name == cousin_name:
                    print(
                        "{} is your cousin, {} times removed, and she lives at {}"
                        "".format(f.name, removed, f.path)
                    )
                    return f.path
        parent_folder = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(folder, os.pardir))
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a modified version of A H's answer just with Micah Culpepper's exit condition and simplified.

```
import os
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

while  "Input_Data" not in os.listdir(path):
  if path == os.path.dirname(path):
    raise FileNotFoundError("could not find Input_Data")
  path = os.path.dirname(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a solution:

1. Using **Pathlib**
2. Taking care of the case where the folder does not exist

```
from pathlib import Path, PosixPath
from typing import Union

def find_root_path(path: Union[str, Path], folder_name: str):
    path = Path(path)
    if path.parent == PosixPath('/'):
        raise FileNotFoundError(f"Unable to find {folder_name}")
    elif (path / folder_name).is_dir():
        return path
    else:
        return find_root_path(path.parent)
```

If you want to find a file, use `is_file()` instead of `is_dir()` or, if you want to support both use `.exists()`. [Reference](https://datagy.io/python-check-if-file-directory-exists/)